# Why is the Perl "doesn't match" operator not working here?

Tags: regex, string, perl, conditional-statements

I have the following Perl code:

```
my $athCombined = "$athSymbol $athExpiration $athStrike $athType";
if (($instrumentType eq "STOCK" && $cbSymbol ne $athSymbol) ||
    ($instrumentType eq "OPTION" && $cbSymbol !~ /^$athSymbol.*$athExpiration $athStrike $athType$/) ||
    ($instrumentType eq "FUTURESOPTION" && $cbSymbol !~ /^$athCombined$/)) {
    print "ERROR: Symbols on lines $cbLineNum and $athLineNum don't match.  ABORTING.\n";
    print "instrumentType    =$instrumentType\n";
    print "cbSymbol          =$cbSymbol\n";
    print "athCombined       =$athCombined\n";
    print "length cbSymbol   =" . length($cbSymbol) . "\n";
    print "length athCombined=" . length($athCombined) . "\n";
    if ($instrumentType eq "FUTURESOPTION") {
        print "YES1\n";
    }
    if ($cbSymbol !~ /^$athCombined$/) {
        print "YES2\n";
    }
    if ($cbSymbol eq $athCombined) {
        print "they are the same\n";
    }
    exit;
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
ERROR: Symbols on lines 434 and 1906 don't match.  ABORTING.
instrumentType    =FUTURESOPTION
cbSymbol          =/ESM19 1/50 JUN 19 (Monday) (Wk1) /E1AM19 2745 CALL
athCombined       =/ESM19 1/50 JUN 19 (Monday) (Wk1) /E1AM19 2745 CALL
length cbSymbol   =51
length athCombined=51
YES1
YES2
they are the same
```

The conditional `$cbSymbol !~ /^$athCombined$/` is returning true even though `$cbSymbol` and `$athCombined` are the same.  If I change the conditional to `cbSymbol ne $athCombined`, then it works correctly, but I'd like to know why it is not working as is.

Interestingly, I am not able to reproduce this in a simple test program:

```
my $a = "1";
my $b = "2";
my $c = "3";
my $abc = "1 2 3";
my $def = "$a $b $c";
if ($abc !~ /^$def$/) {
    print "something is wrong\n";
}
```

"something is wrong" does not get printed out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$foo !~ /^$bar$/` is not equivalent to checking for string inequality, as in `$foo ne $bar`. It checks if `$foo` does not match the regex `^$bar$`, which differs especially if `$bar` contains regex metacharacters, but also in that `$` can match before (allow) a trailing newline and not only at the end of the string. (`\z` is the equivalent of `$` that does not allow for a trailing newline.)

`$athCombined` in your program is `/ESM19 1/50 JUN 19 (Monday) (Wk1) /E1AM19 2745 CALL`, which contains the regex metacharacters `(` and `)` (in this case they form capture groups and thus the literal parentheses in your other string are not matched by anything). You can solve this by using [quotemeta modifiers](https://perldoc.pl/perlrebackslash#Modifiers):

```
$cbSymbol !~ /^\Q$athCombined\E\z/
```

but better would just be to use the string equality operators `eq` or `ne` if that's what you're trying to test.